# Is there is a way to see the size of the selection rectangle in Paint.NET

Tags: paint.net

Is there is a way to see the size of the selection rectangle in Paint.NET e.g. if I select a 5x5 square, can I see that is it 5x5 without having to count pixels.

I know there is a ruler on the side, but it also requires you to calculate.

Comment: I believe you can see that info at the bottom of the application window.

Comment: It should be on the same bar as the zoom slider.

Comment: That's where I would expect it too, but it is not there, hence my question: http://screencast.com/t/4m4slNTKu0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's on the bottom left corner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are actually three ways to view your dimensions. Go to 'View', scroll down and select one of the available options:

- pixels
- inches
- centimeters

Now whatever size you draw, it will show the value based on one of the mentioned values chosen above.